# Couldn`t load static files with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, angular, flask

I am newbie to both Angular and Flask and this question is kinda embarrassing.

So I have completed all steps of ngx-admin installation like [here](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/#/docs/installation/based-on-starter-kit-ngxadmin).
*npm run build* script compiled everything to the same folder so the directory structure looks as follows:

```
/flask-test
    server.py
    /ngx-admin
        /dist  -  all built files 
        /src
        /node_modules
```

Now I am trying to connect everything to server.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__,static_folder="./ngx-admin/dist",template_folder="./ngx-admin/dist")

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And I keep receiving multiple 404 errors, but all files server couldn`t find are present in */ngx-admin/dist* folder. 
[image: screenshot]

As I understood the problem is with static directory. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html` template should reference those resources using `/static`.

`<script src="main.bundle.js"></script>`

would become

`<script src="/static/main.bundle.js"></script>`

also be sure to create a `static` folder under `/flask-test` and put your css and js files in that folder.